# Getting a value from dynamically created textbox through php

Tags: php, html

I have n number of text box (n may be any number) with same name. And
I want to access the value of all the text box of that name.

Ex-:

```
<form method="post" id="create">
<input type="text" name="user[]" />
<input type="text" name="user[]" />
<input type="text" name="user[]" />
<input type="button" id="newFieldBtn"/>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="save"/>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#newFieldBtn').click(function(){
var code='<input type="text" name="user[]" />';
jQuery('#create').append(code);

</script>
```

or is there any other way to access the value of the text box. Either
by class or any other property..

Comment: how you are generation your `textboxes`? I mean by using `php` or `javascript/jquery`? you can use `count` ....

Comment: Since you are asking about accessing the send value in PHP – no, apart from the value the name is the only info you get send; classes or anything else client-side do not come into play. But what is your question anyway, where is the _problem_ in accessing the values?

Comment: I am using jQuery for add new text box

Comment: Now see my code @ Nishant Solanki

Comment: $_POST['user'] return only "Array", i Can't Get the value Of user[0],user[1]...etc

Comment: @Boopathi check my ans...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#newFieldBtn').click(function(){
    var count = document.getElementById('count').value;
    count++;
    var code = '<input type="text" name="user'+count+'" />';
            jQuery('#create').append(code);
            document.getElementById('count').value = count;
</script>
```

and your html like...

```
<form method="post" id="create">
    <input type="hidden" id="count" value="0" name="count">
    <input type="button" id="newFieldBtn"/>
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="save"/>
</form>
```

and in your php code...

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST))
{
    $count = $_POST['count'];
    for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++)
    {
        $user.$i = $_POST['user'.$i];
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, it will show you the values :

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="text" name="user[]" />
<input type="text" name="user[]" />
<input type="text" name="user[]" />
 <input type="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{ 
 foreach($_POST['user'] as $key => $value)
{
  echo $key." has the value = ". $value."<br>";
}
}
?>
```

See this in action: http://wistudat.be/try/array.php