# Accessing values from dynamically generated textboxes in php

Tags: php, textbox

First user will enter that how many textboxes he want to create.
for example he select 4 from list, then 4 textboxes will be created.
After that these, code will create textboxes dynamically in php and send its values to another php page.
 kindly help to complete this task.

Comment: Have you done some starting code to share with us?

Comment: That's the best way for us to help you

Comment: thanks for reply ... @nanocv  ...some part is solved in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630864/getting-a-value-from-dynamically-created-textbox-through-php

Comment: but it need to be customize.

Comment: Ok, give me a moment and I'll write you a code, but I think the best way to create the "textboxes" (textareas I guess) dinamically is with Javascript.

Comment: thanks....  i am waiting...

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label for="inputTextareasNumber">How many textareas do you want?</label>
        <input type="number" id="inputTextareasNumber" min="1">
        <button type="button" id="butCreateTextareas">Create textareas</button>

        <form id="myDynamicForm" action="myPHPfile.php" method="post"></form>

        <script>
            /* HTML elements caching */
            var inputTextareasNumber = document.getElementById("inputTextareasNumber");
            var butCreateTextareas = document.getElementById("butCreateTextareas");
            var myDynamicForm = document.getElementById("myDynamicForm");

            /* Create textareas when click button */
            butCreateTextareas.addEventListener("click", createTextareas);

            function createTextareas() {
                /* First we empty the form so we can re-create it with a different number of textareas*/
                emptyElement(myDynamicForm);

                /* Here we get the number of textareas we want */
                var textareasNumber = inputTextareasNumber.value;

                /* We create and append to the form as many textareas as number we wrote in the input */
                for (var i = 1; i <= textareasNumber; i++) {
                    var newTextarea = document.createElement("textarea");
                    newTextarea.name = "myTextarea" + i;
                    myDynamicForm.appendChild(newTextarea);
                }

                /* We crate and append the submit button */
                var submitButton = document.createElement("input");
                submitButton.type = "submit";
                submitButton.value = "Send";
                myDynamicForm.appendChild(submitButton);
            }

            /* Empty any HTML element */
            function emptyElement(element) {
                while (element.lastChild) {
                    element.removeChild(element.lastChild);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here you have it working: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frvoo15s/)

A very very basic PHP receiver could be this **(myPHPfile.php)**:

```
<?php

foreach ($_POST as $textareaValue) {
    echo "<p>$textareaValue</p>";
}
```

Comment: Great! If you need any help with this code or with the PHP receiver just let me know

Comment: one more thing ... if you don't mind. kindly write code that ... How to receive theses textboxes values in another php page.

Comment: Sure. What do you want to do with the values? Just show them on the screen?

Comment: Actually i am making different web pages ...on the basis of textboxes

Comment: Ok, then the standard answer is: if you send the form with the "get" method, you will have an array variable called "$_GET" in the PHP receiver. The array will have as many positions as textareas you created.

Comment: @nonocv ... How can i customize this code this if(isset($_POST))
{
    $count = $_POST['count'];
    for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++)
    {
        $user.$i = $_POST['user'.$i];
    }
}                          with respect to your code...

Comment: I just updated the answer. I used the foreach loop to go through all the values (I think is cleaner). If you prefer to send the form with the "post" method let me know and I will change it (it has to be changed in the HTML code and in the PHP code).

Comment: it is still working .....but if you can change to post method... it will be better ..thank a lot in adnvace

Comment: Edited! Now you have it working with post method. If you need more help with this code just write me here! Please, remember validating the answer :)

Comment: Thanks... i have validated the code.its works perfectly... Thanks again... @nanocv